# Render different content on AMP depending on device (iPhone or Android)

Tags: php, amp-html

I want to create dynamic content depending on the device of the user.

For example, if the user is browsing the AMP version on my website using an 
iPhone, my app download link should render as:
**Download for iPhone** (href = app store link)

However, if the user is browsing using an Android device, I would like to render the download app link as:
**Download for Android** (href = google play link)

The problem is that AMP pages are cached and I do not know how to render the content dynamically depending on device type.

Comment: Usually you see both icons/links (what if you want to send link to friend on Android, but you are using wePhone?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you can achieve this by using `amp-access`. If you could identify the device from `user-agent` in the `authorization` request from `amp-access` and set a flag in your `amp-access` response `AUTHDATA`, then you can conditionally render the button.

Comment: are you sure that the authorization endpoint receives the User Agent?

Comment: @UriAbramson I just checked and can confirm that the authorization endpoint receives `user-agent` in the request header. I accessed it using `req.headers["user-agent"]` and got value `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1` since I was using an emulator

Comment: @UriAbramson Could you provide a sample of the configuration you did to achieve the solution?

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony Could you provide a sample of the configuration you did to achieve this solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://glitch.com/~tasteful-swift) is an example using amp-access. In the authorization request, you can access user-agent so will be setting the type of device here. In the example, it basically checks for android in /deviedetection if not then it returns iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this plugin to detect the device and then load the right AMP content based on the device type (IOS/Android).

[Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

Comment: This will not work with AMP because it is cached not even on my server. I can't control which version is getting cached.